# Batch script to open text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script to read a text file. It's working fine if the file name doesn't contain special characters, but it's failing if the file name contains special characters.

Ex file name: `localhost_access_log.2013-03-08`

Code:

```
for /f "skip=%* tokens=*" %%b in (Y:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs\localhost_access_log.2013-03-08.txt) do (
    echo "Data Copied"
)
```

Please help me how to read these kind of files.

Comment: Put the filename in quotes "...". Otherwise, filenames with blanks are not properly recognized.

Comment: ... and add the `usebackq` option.

Comment: What are special characters for you? (nota bene: To me that would be characters outside of Unicode, which would be *very* special)

Comment: @Joey: I believe the OP is referring to spaces in the path.  user2148537: if I'm wrong, then edit your question to show us one of those names it's failing on, and tell us what the error message is.

Answer (score 1):

Type `help for` at the command line to get the documentation on the for command (which I admit is rather hard to read), and you get this buried about halfway down:

```
For file names that contain spaces, you need to quote the filenames with
double quotes.  In order to use double quotes in this manner, you also
need to use the usebackq option, otherwise the double quotes will be
interpreted as defining a literal string to parse.
```

So your code should change to this:

```
for /f "usebackq skip=%* tokens=*" %%b in ("Y:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs\localhost_access_log.2013-03-08.txt") do (
    echo "Data Copied"
)
```